# Android - Method addObserver must be called on the main thread

Tags: android, react-native

I got this error trying to setup Revenue Cat Purchases 3.4.3 on React Native.
RN 0.67

***2022-02-28 07:58:39.154 5945-8093/com.farms E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method addObserver must be called on the main thread
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.enforceMainThreadIfNeeded(LifecycleRegistry.java:317)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:172)
at com.revenuecat.purchases.Purchases.(Purchases.kt:160)
at com.revenuecat.purchases.Purchases$Companion.configure(Purchases.kt:1593)
at com.revenuecat.purchases.Purchases$Companion.configure$default(Purchases.kt:1560)
at com.revenuecat.purchases.common.CommonKt.configure(common.kt:271)
at com.revenuecat.purchases.react.RNPurchasesModule.setupPurchases(RNPurchasesModule.java:73)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)***

Anyone faced it? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Ok! Updating to react-native-purchases 4.5.2 solves the problem!